# Are mutual fund dividend information per month/quarter and also per share/dollar

Tags: mutual-funds

I am wondering are mutual fund dividend information

- per month OR per quarter
- per share OR per dollar

For example, [fsdix](https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/funds-and-etfs/fsdix)

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mutual funds *typically* pay dividends (and disburse capital gains) quarterly, but check the history and/or the prospectus to be sure. Some funds that are geared more towards dividend income pay monthly, and some pay annually. Looking at the dividend history of this fund, it is paid quarterly.

The dividend is *per unit*, which is roughly equivalent to "per share" in single stocks. When you invest in a mutual fund, you buy a dollar amount, and the number of units you get will be the total amount dividend by the per-unit price at the close of that day. You don't buy units or shares in blocks like you do with stocks.

Also note that the dividend is not *fixed* - you often get a larger dividend at the end of the year when the fund disburses capital gains or other income for tax purposes.